Static vs. Contextualized Embeddings
What is an embedding approach that uses a network architecture that is similar to an auto-encoder with one hidden layer? Which one is it? What is the input? what is the output? What part constitutes the embedding vector in the model?
I am not sure if the answer is Word2Vec.

Is this a homework/test? Auto-encoders work by passing any input through the network, with desire for the network to output exactly the input. And if the hidden representation is smaller than input, then you can say that you "compressed" the input into this hidden representation, because the network can then return the output from the hidden representation, so the hidden representation is sufficient to represent (embed) the data
